# Can AAD federate with Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, federated-identity, azure-ad-b2c

Can an app in one Azure AD tenant be configured to federate with another Azure B2C tenant?

ie, I have an AAD with an app registered, and want to use a different Azure B2C tenant as my identity provider.

So my app can allow users from that Azure B2C tenant to sign in.

Like how B2C can federate with social identity providers (Google/Facebook), I would like my AAD app to sign users in through another Azure B2C tenant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible federation between Azure AD and Azure AD B2C.

You can use both (Azure AD and Azure AD B2C), but you must manage each App Registration individually.

Here you can **[Set up sign-up and sign-in with a Google account using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-user-flow)**

And here you can **[Set up sign-up and sign-in with a Facebook account using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-facebook?pivots=b2c-user-flow)**

Hope this help!